# Determine empty column with Nothing, = Nothing or IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: sql, vb.net, isnullorempty

When you want to determine if a database column is empty (i.e not null but there is not any value in it) what are the differences between the below options:

`customerRegion varchar(10) NULL` is retrieved from the SQL database:

1. `If customerRegion = "" Then`
2. `If customerRegion = Nothing Then`
3. `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerRegion) Then`
4. `If customerRegion Is Nothing Then`

1,2,3 returns True 4 returns False when the column is empty.

Is 1 and 2 technically the same thing? and Why is 4 returning False?

Out of 1,2 and 3 which one should be used to determine if the column is empty (or is there any other way of doing it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `If customerRegion = "" Then` - This tests to see if the column contains an empty (0 length) string.  This is the "best" option because the value will never be `Nothing`.  If the column value was null, it would equal `DBNull`, not `Nothing`.
2. `If customerRegion = Nothing Then` - This is very confusing because many people will think it's interchangeable with #4 (`Is Nothing`).  When you test if a string equals `Nothing`, VB.NET automatically considers `Nothing` to be an empty string.  That is why it evaluates to True.
3. `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerRegion) Then` - This will work well, but it's unnecessary since the column value will never be null (`Nothing`) (see #1).
4. `If customerRegion Is Nothing Then` - This will never return true (see #1).

Answer (score 1):

- No, they are not the same. The #2 will return `True` if the value is actually `Nothing`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx):

> For strings in Visual Basic, the empty string equals Nothing. Therefore, "" = Nothing is true.

So the behavior has to do with VB-specific handling of `= Nothing` with strings.

- Number 4 returns `False` because the string is empty, but it is not `Nothing`.
- There is another check that you can do: `IsNullOrWhitespace`. But if you need to detect specifically strings of zero length, you should compare them to [`String.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx).

Like this:

```
If customerRegion = String.Empty Then
```